# "php fatal error" using pg_connect

Tags: php

I have installed php5 and php5-pgsql on my ubuntu(linux mint). And i can not get result of query in php script:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=user")
or die("Could not connect: test db\n"); 
$part = $db->query("SELECT * FROM app_settings");
```

This query works right, running in pg_admin and all db connection attributes are right!

But i got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function pg_query() on a non-object in
```

What's the problem, help pls!

Comment: Have you considered to use PDO?

Comment: no, i want to solve this problem as simple as it possible...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing pg_* functions and PDO. `pg_connect()` does not return an object, it returns a connection resource for later use in `pg_query()`. You can do it either way:

```
$res = pg_connect(...);
$result = pg_query($res, "SQL query"); // where $res is optional if you only use one connection at a time
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  // ...
}
```

or you use PDO

```
$db = new PDO("...");
$db->query("SQL query");
// ...
```

I'd prefer [PDO with prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really mixed this functions, from different examples)

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling pgsql in PHP.ini file

add this line in the extensions

```
extension=pgsql.so
```

Update:

Not sure that is right. What about this.

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=user")
or die("Could not connect: test db\n"); 
$part = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM app_settings");

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($part)) {
 //do stuff

}
```

Comment: I do it, but nothing changes. Should i restart anything?)

Comment: what webserver are you running? try restarting whatever web service you have.

Comment: ah, something changes) in error added this string:
    PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: There are two ways to load most extensions in PHP. One is by compiling the extension directly into the PHP binary. The other is by loading a shared extension dynamically via an ini file. The errors indicate that dynamic extensions are being loaded via .ini files, even though they are already compiled into the PHP binary. So, comment out the line in the `ini` file.

Comment: Haha, yes, I was updating my answer when he posted. it's the same. Glad you got it working. if it's helpful you can always upvote the answer.

Comment: I want but i can't. Not enough reputation)

Comment: @dio_bless: you would gain reputation if you accepted the answers to your questions.